# How to encrypt java object and send it as String in URL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Java object in which I have product information. This information I want to send to controller in URL using Get method. I want to send this object as encrypted string format.In the controller I want to decrypt information and get the values from the object. Or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: If you're concerned about the visibility of data in transit then use an SSL connection and then all the difficult-to-get-right cryptography is done for you.

Comment: 1. Generate json; 2. Encrypt it with RSA for example 3. Send it over https 4. Decrypt 5. Parse json to object.

Comment: Thanks @MladenSavić I am following the approach you suggested.